# Bigcommerce custom template for subcategory

Tags: bigcommerce

Newbie here. I'm trying to create a custom template for a subcategory. I'm working locally using the stencil cli and Visual Studio Code. I created the following:

---

```
templates/pages/custom/category/_category-3d-series.html.
```

Then I updated `config.stencil.json`, the following code, setting the `category` to match my store's [URL](https://smt-wheels.mybigcommerce.com/product-category/wheels/3d-series/):

```
"customLayouts": "category": "_category-3d-series.html":"/3d-series/"
```

---

Then I run `stencil start` in `PowerShell`, but when I check my site locally, it's not using the custom page I created, I can tell because I put *"this is my 3D category!"* in the `.html` file. And I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have proper JSON syntax. (Specifically, you're missing `{` and `}` characters in multiple places.)

```html
{
  "customLayouts": {
    "category": {"_category-3d-series.html":"/3d-series/"},
  }
}
```

I haven't seen a template name prefixed with an underscore before, though I don't have any reason to think that would cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"customLayouts": {
"category": {
"_category-3d-series.html": ["/3d-series/"]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "customLayouts": {
    "category": {
      "{{customTemplate}}.html" :["{{url}}"]
    }
  }
}
```

After adding this to config.stencil.json you need to rerun stencil start.